# HTML a href alignment

Tags: html, css

Currently, this is my code:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  a {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 90%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

How do I align my `hyperlink` to the right side?

Currently, if I am using `float:left`, it will be stacked with my other element.

***Example***

[image]

> Fixed with the code > "clear: both" .

Comment: Use `div` which has `text-align: right`? With contains your `a`?

Comment: please provide the full code with codepen link.

Comment: Use CSS property `clear: both` just upper div of this hyperlink

Comment: umm.. float:right??

Comment: Thanks @AlokMali fixed with the code you provided. Wondered that why used float and it will overlapped with the element

Comment: You are most welcome @greenboxgoolu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wish you had explained your problem better along with your HTML code. Anyway, you can use display flex that is much better than float. Or you can use text-align: right.
if you want them on one row, delete flex-direction.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">click</a>

  <a href="#">click</a>

  <a href="#">click</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for align right the link:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  a {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 90%;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In in order to make the anchor tag go the right you would need to use float right instead of float left. You can also align the text to the left

```css
.linkright a {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2rem;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkright">
  <a href="#"> click me! </a>
</div>
```